# How to set borders in CSS correctly without crossing on next div?

Tags: html, css

I have problem setting up borders on columns. Text is changing size of div so the border change.  I have tried to set fixed size of divs but it wasn't good. I am not sure why are borders moving. Is it for padding? I am beginner and its hard  for me to get it right way. Hoe to make it fixed, without crossing to next div?
[image]

HERE IS HTML:

```
<div class="container full-width margin-bottom-x">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 fund-text">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 no-padding">
                                <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                                <img src="http://mezet.xyz/romeda/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/funds-projects-01.png" alt="Fund project" />
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>Russia’s leading auto leasing company. Fully exited in 2015.</p> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-funds">More details</button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 fund-text">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 no-padding">
                                <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                                <img src="http://mezet.xyz/romeda/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/fund-projects-02.png" alt="Fund project" />
                                </div>
                        </div>
                <p>Russia’s largest Internet company and leading 
        search engine.</p> 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-funds">More details</button>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 fund-text">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 no-padding">
                    <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:0px;">
                        <img src="http://mezet.xyz/romeda/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/fund-projects-03.png" alt="Fund project" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>The leading e-commerce platform in Russia and the CIS.</p> 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-funds">More details</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 fund-text">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 no-padding">
                        <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:0px;">
                                <img src="http://mezet.xyz/romeda/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/fund-projects-04.png" alt="Fund project" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                        <p>Independent oil and gas company.</p> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-funds">More details</button>
             </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.fund-views{
    font-family: Roboto;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;

}
.fund-views .fund-text {
    padding: 90px;
    padding-left: 160px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.fund-views .fund-text p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
      text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: you may delete the common border, for example keep the left of one col and delete the right of its neighboor

Comment: left-right borders are not a problem. Top and bottom are.

Comment: so you may do the same, remove bottom border from top element and keep top border for bottom element

Comment: You should keep a fixed height for the containers, set a `height: auto` value for the content (in your case there's no `height` value specified, it's ok), and center them in their container (it means you will also delete the top & bottom paddings of the content to make it work properly).

Comment: Thank you @AymDev. It works.